# Boundedness of $A^{-1} P A$ where P is projector and A unbounded

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Take a Hilbert space $H$, an orthogonal projector $P$, an unbounded self-adjoint operator $A$. Is $A^{-1} P A$ bounded ?

Comment: Hi, please provide what you've attempted, what you know about the problem statement, and any relevant motivation as to why you're attempting to understand / prove about this statement.